# How to do disjoint classification without softmax output?

Tags: neural-network, fann

What's the correct way to do 'disjoint' classification (where the outputs are mutually exclusive, i.e. true probabilities sum to 1) in FANN since it doesn't seems to have an option for softmax output?

My understanding is that using sigmoid outputs, as if doing 'labeling', that I wouldn't be getting the correct results for a classification problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FANN only supports `tanh` and `linear` error functions. This means, as you say, that the probabilities output by the neural network will not sum to 1. There is no easy solution to implementing a `softmax` output, as this will mean changing the cost function and hence the error function used in the backpropagation routine. As FANN is open source you could have a look at implementing this yourself. A question on Cross Validated seems to give the equations you would have to [implement](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79454/softmax-layer-in-a-neural-network).

Although not the mathematically elegant solution you are looking for, I would try play around with some cruder approaches before tackling the implementation of a `softmax` cost function - as one of these might be sufficient for your purposes. For example, you could use a `tanh` error function and then just renormalise all the outputs to sum to 1. Or, if you are actually only interested in what the most likely classification is you could just take the output with the highest score.

Steffen Nissen, the guy behind FANN, presents an example [here](http://fann.sourceforge.net/fann_en.pdf) where he tries to classify what language a text is written in based on letter frequency. I think he uses a `tanh` error function (default) and just takes the class with the biggest score, but he indicates that it works well.